# Capybara redirect from http to https how?

Tags: rspec, capybara

I try find the way to check with Capybara
Thats protocol is changed when user visit any page:
( in app/controllers/application.rb I perform redirect to https instead http )
How to check this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
current_url.should match /^https:/
```

Comment: When I use Rack::Test it always return http. I'm not sure maybe it's some request Mock. but I get https:// only when add something like env['protocol'] = 'https://' (not sure about exact value in brackets)